# JProbe for profiling a Java EE application

Tags: performance, profiling, jprobe

I am using JProbe for profiling a Java EE application.

From the Load tester (JMeter) I have executed 2000 requests for testing the Application.

I have seen that all the 2000 request have passed given from JMeter.

Now my question is, even though 2000 requests haven been executed, but still on the JProbe why there are Threads shown indicating, Waiting and in Blocked State?

Please see the following screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unable to view screen short attached.

If i understood scenario correctly, you fired 2000 requests (executed from JMeter) but JPre indicating threads in waiting and blocked state.

- Either typical case of the dead-lock. If it really is a deadlock, then look-out for the synchronized block in your code.
- If it's JProbe issue, try with other profiling tool such as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html provided by java.